# Calling component's method from class

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a material 2 [sidenav](https://material.angular.io/components/component/sidenav) component in my application. How can I access the component methods from my class? In my case, I want to call the `open()` method. In template works with `<button md-button (click)="sidenav.open()">` perfectly fine, but if I use the method in class via `this.el.nativeElement.open();`, it throws:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined

**My component:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidebar-content',
  template: `
    <md-sidenav-container class="example-container">

      <md-sidenav #sidenav class="example-sidenav">
        Jolly good!
      </md-sidenav>

      <div class="example-sidenav-content">
        <button md-button (click)="sidenav.open()">
          Open sidenav
        </button>
      </div>

    </md-sidenav-container>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./sidebar-content.component.css']
})
export class SidebarContentComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('sidenav') el: ElementRef;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  openSideNav() {
    // this.el.nativeElement.open();
    // ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined
  }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're misusing `ViewChild`.
Take a look at the official documentation of ViewChild: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewChild-decorator.html

ViewChild takes the class type of the component you want to track. In your case it's `MdSidenav` I suppose.
You should change your code as follows to be able to access the first `sidenav` component that you injected in the template:

```
export class SidebarContentComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild(MdSidenav) sidenav: MdSidenav;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  openSideNav() {
    this.sidenav.open();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your `@ViewChild` like so:

`@ViewChild('sidenav', {read: ComponentRef}) c: ComponentRef;`

Then you can access the instance methods like this.

`c.instance.open()`

Edit:

Or you can just specify the Type as your component type like the other answer said...